# UML Use case diagram work schedule

Tags: uml, software-design, use-case

I've recently been learning about UML use case diagrams and I have a few minor questions about this UML case diagram that I have created.

[image]

1. Does view schedule `<<extend>>` from create schedule?
2. If yes, then does this work properly by including the Login?
3. Is it necessary to `<<include>>` username/password for the login or should I simply have "Login" without username/pass

p.s. I know this is very basic but i'm unsure about whether or not I've got the hang of this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of issues.

- The `<<include>>` is meant to include UCs, not objects. Since `Vehicles`/`Drivers`/... are not UCs that's wrong.
- The fact that `Create schedule` extends `View schedule` seems odd. To me both are individual and independent UCs.
- Finally `Login` is no (business) UC. It is a constraint which is to be applied to `View schedule`. Attach a `<<invariant>> {must be logged on}` to the connector to `User`

Remember: a UC is about added value for an actor. That's what the UC is named after. For that reason `Login` is no UC (but a constraint). Avoid include/extend since it is a sign of using functional decomposition. UC is about the opposite: synthesizing work steps that belong to a single added value.